# Java DAO pattern and runtime dependencies

Tags: java, dao, packaging

We have implemented a typical DAO/Abstract Factory pattern. The design is like this:

DAOFactory - that returns either an instance of MySQLFactory / SQLiteFactory

- MySQLFactory - returns DAOs that talks to MySQL DB
- SQLiteFactory - returns DAOs that talks to SQLite DB

Things are fine. However, we need to create two executables: The one that is provided to customers uses the SQLiteFactory instance and relevant DAOs. In that executable, we don't want to include any class related to MySQLFactory. If I delete those classes then we see a ClassNotFoundException at run time when DAOFactory class is being loaded by class loader.

How can we implement our DAOFactory so that MySQLFactory is not required at runtime ? The same problem also exists for certain other classes i.e. certain classes are required only for in-house version of the app. What is a good way of implementation so that we can exclude classes from the software that is shipped to customers ?

Thanks
Deep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Class.forName`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29) to load classes at runtime. For example:

```
public class DAOFactoryLoader {
  public static DAOFactory loadMySQLFactory() {
    return (DAOFactory) Class.forName("your.package.MySQLFactory").newInstance();
  }

  public static DAOFactory loadSQLiteFactory() {
    return (DAOFactory) Class.forName("your.package.SQLiteFactory").newInstance();
  }
}
```

Then you can call the right method for the specific version of your software, i.e. `loadMySQLFactory` when you bundle the MySQL implementation and `loadSQLiteFactory` when you bundle the SQLite implementation.

You can even pass the class name as a JVM property, for eg. `-DdaoFactory=your.package.MySQLFactory` and then use this to load the right class:

```
return (DAOFactory) Class.forName(System.getProperty("daoFactory")).newInstance();
```